# using opensans font - text is not centered vertically

Tags: html, css, fonts

```css
.parent{
display:inline-block;
border:2px solid #555;
padding:0 14px;
line-height:25px;
font-family:'Open Sans';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

<div class='parent'>LOREM IPSUM</div>
```

Using `OpenSans` the text `LOREM IPSUM` is not centered vertically. I think it is two pixels raised up.

Any help?

Comment: include the font in your snippet  https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans?selection.family=Open+Sans

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I did, thanks.

Comment: I won't talk about *centring* here but how font are rendred considering line-height/font-size beause technically you did nothing to center your text

Answer (score 1):

**REASON**

The default font-size in browsers is 16px.

Substract line-height with fontsize: 25px - 16px = 9px
This is an odd number and will be divided in 5px and 4px. That's why one side is 1px bigger.

**FIX**

Use **em** instead of **px**:

```
line-height: 1.5em;
```

You can also set the line-height 1 pixel higher (26px) or add 1px padding to top, but I don't think that's the proper solution.

Comment: *Using the line-height property will also change the font-size* : this is false, font-size has nothing to do with line-height ..defining one will not change the other. Try different line-height and the text size will not change

Comment: also note that his problem raised when using a specific font-family. your answer implies that this is a generic issue

Comment: My bad. The default font-size is 16px (not by calculation but by definition).